# "df." as an abbreviation

Tags: abbreviations, mathematics

I'm reading a book and I stumbled upon the following paragraph, in context of doing a conceptual analysis, to quote:

> **Ml:** Motherhood  is  the  conjunction  of  femaleness  and  parent-hood.
> **M2:** To be a mother  is to  be a female parent.
> **M3:** Being a mother  is being  a female parent.
> **M4:** 'Mother' means the  same as 'female parent'.
> **M5:** x is a mother  at t  =  **df.** x is a female parent  at  t.

For the life of me I cannot figure out what that "**df.**" in the last sentence supposed to mean.

[The Book: *Confrontations with the Reaper*](https://books.google.com/books?id=WMXhBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT24&dq=Motherhood%20is%20the%20conjunction%20of%20femaleness%20and%20parent-hood.&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9rraw0rTsAhUdlHIEHWsgA40Q6AEwAHoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=Motherhood%20is%20the%20conjunction%20of%20femaleness%20and%20parent-hood.&f=false)

Comment: The symbol seems to be = with df or perhaps df. as a suhscript, and many situations can't handle the subscript. It is so unusual that it must be considered non-standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I disagree with Greybeard.  It is true that this notation is from mathematics (or logic), but here

> =  **df.**

means: "is equal to by definition".

---

It is no longer usual to see this in mathematics, but other areas have retained it.
A web search found [LINK1](http://www.ditext.com/reichenbach/logic/5.html) and [LINK2](https://www.chegg.com/flashcards/ethics-final-exam-f79a4bab-ac40-4658-9ce9-3174ce6e85cc/deck).  At
[LINK3](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Eanne/WQ2007/mat67-Common_Math_Symbols.pdf) it is shown as = with subscript "Def", and attributed to Cesare Burali-Forti, 1894.

---

Parse

> *x* is a mother  at t  =  **df.** *x* is a female parent  at  *t*.

as

> [*x* is a mother  at *t*]  =**df.** [*x* is a female parent  at  *t*].

That is,

> [*x* is a mother  at *t*]  is by definition the same as [*x* is a female parent  at  *t*]

We haven't seen the original (we haven't even been told what book it is), but I would guess it is printed as an equal sign "=" with "**df.**" as a subscript.

Comment: Can you add a reference? This answer makes a lot of sense bur I’ve never seen this notation, so it would be good to have an authoritative citation.

Comment: How do you explain "***t*** = df."?

Comment: In support of this, I appear to have found the book (added link), and it prefaces "M5" with the comment "[...] I happen to prefer to formulate analyses as definitions [...]"

Comment: The correct way of rendering this symbol has *def* or *df.* **above** the *equals* sign, like this: ≝ . The only possible excuse for its appearing with *df.* next to the equals sign in the text that the OP has seen is that the typesetter was not able to reproduce the sign properly, and resorted to this as a close-enough approximation.

Comment: I didn't add the book because well it's very pessimistic for the times. Thanks a lot for your research and answer!

Answer (score 2):

The symbol that the author actually intended to appear there is:

## ≝

It means that what is of one side of it is defined as what is on the other side. Its ‘home’ is in formal logic, where the expressions on both sides of it would be formulated by using logical symbols, as in, for example:

M(x,y)≝P(x,y)&F(x)

Once such a definition is introduced, it can be invoked in any proofs that follow, as the ground for treating the expressions on the two sides of the symbol as interchangeable.

Professional philosophers, when writing for philosophically trained audiences, which can be presumed to be familiar with the symbol, sometimes use it informally to connect ordinary English expressions, and that was done in the example that the OP encountered.

The symbol looks like an equals sign with *def* or *df.* **above** the top line. It, however, occasionally happened in the past that the typesetters were not equipped to render this symbol properly; they then resorted to placing *df.* next to the equals sign, which is what the OP has seen. While that may have been the best available substitute under the circumstances, it is confusing, because it may leave an impression that *df.* is a part of the expression on the right side of the symbol, rather than a part of the symbol. The problem should not appear in anything that is published today, as the present-day software makes it easy to render the symbol correctly.

Answer (score -4):

**df** originates in the mathematical operation of differentiation.

**d**f = **delta** 'f' where '**f**' represents a particular function (condition or state), and **delta f** = one **point in time** on the line of **f** with respect to '**t**' another variable - in this case, time, which is symbolised as '**t**'.

From the context "**f**" seems to "being female" or "the female".

*M5: x is a mother at **t = df**. x is a female parent at **t**.*

Here both sentences are the same, the second merely substitutes "female parent" for "mother".

This gives us

M5: x (the woman/subject) is a mother at a specific time where that time, **t**. is a specific point in her life as a woman.

x (the woman/subject) is a female parent at **t**, i.e. a specific point in her life as a woman.